# How can I define a correct architeture to an user control at Windows Forms with pattern MVP(Passive)?

Tags: c#, mvp

I chose the pattern MVP(Passive). This is my first implementation in MVP and I have a lot of doubts. I've already looked few sites and watched videos, but it was not enough to give me an idea of how I should proceed.

There are three controls in my view, but only one will be displaying at a time. There's a method called in the presenter **ConfigureCurrentWindow(FieldType type)** that it is responsable to get the type and update the view to show the right control. Only one control can be visible at a time.

The way that I chose update the view with the methods (ConfigureCurrentWindow & Focus). Did I choose correct implematation or I broke the architeture MVP(Passive)?

In my head there will be two presenters and two views. one presenter for user control and another one the form displayed to the user. Is that way right?

I saw in some sites that should use a event handler to user interactions. why I cannot call a method like this"_presenter.TextChanged()" in my view?

How should I get the value"text" from the right control? Where should I implement a method to get the value?

**Model**

```cs
public interface IInputDialogModel : IModel
{
    FieldType Type { get; set; }

    string Description { get; set; }

    string Text {get;set;}
    //I've omitted some properties 

    void OnValueChanged(Object sender, InputDialogEventArgs e);
    event EventHandler<InputDialogEventArgs> ValueChanged;

    void OnValueCompleted(Object sender, InputDialogEventArgs e);
    event EventHandler<InputDialogEventArgs> ValueCompleted;
}
```

**View**

```cs
public interface IInputDialogView : IView
{

    string Title { get; set; }

    string InputText { get; set; }

    string Description { get; set; }

    bool Required { get; set; }
    //I've omitted some properties

    event EventHandler<EventArgs> InputValueChanged;

    void Focus(FieldType type);

    void SetErrorProvider(string message);

    void ClearErrorProvider();

}
```

**Concrete View**

```cs
public partial class InputDialogForm : Form, IInputDialogView
{
    private InputDialogModalPresenter _presenter;
    #region Interface
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> InputValueChanged;


    public string Title { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public bool MultiLine { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public FormBorderStyle BorderStyle { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public string InputText { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    //I've omitted some properties
    #endregion


    public InputDialogForm(IInputDialogModel inputDialogModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _presenter = new InputDialogModalPresenter(this, inputDialogModel);
        maskDate.TextChanged += txtInput_TextChanged;
    }

    private void txtInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //InputValueChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
    private void InputDialogForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _presenter.SetFocus();
    }

    void IInputDialogModalView.Focus(FieldType type)
    {
    //I must choose which control must be focused according the Model Type???
        switch (fieldType)
        {
            case FieldType.SingleLine:
                textboxSingle.Focus();
                break;
            case FieldType.MultiLine:
                textboxMulti.Focus();
                break;
            case FieldType.Date:
                maskedDate.Focus();
                break;
        }
    }

    //My principal question is here. I must turn visible the correct panel 
    //by the Model Type. is this implementation right?
    public void ConfigureCurrentWindow(FieldType fieldType)
    {
        Panel currentPanel = null;

        switch (fieldType)
        {
            case FieldType.SingleLine:
                 currentPanel = panelSingleTextBox;
                break;
            case FieldType.MultiLine:
                currentPanel = panelMultiTextBox;
                break;
            case FieldType.Date:
                currentPanel = panelDate;
                break;
        }
        currentPanel.Visible = true;
        currentPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

}
```

**Presenter**

```cs
public class InputDialogPresenter : Presenter<IInputDialogView, IInputDialogModel>{

public InputDialogModalPresenter(IInputDialogModalView view, IInputDialogModel model) :base(view , model)
{
    abstractFactoryInputDialog  =AbstractFactoryInputDialog.GetFactory(view, model);
    LoadInputDialog(view, model);

}

protected override void SubscribeEvents()
{
    View.InputValueChanged += OnValueChanged;
}

public void Focus()
{
    view.Focus(model.Type);
}

public void UpdateView()
{
    view.ConfigureCurrentWindow(model.Type);
}}
```

**Image about the UserControl**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P9Aa.jpg